# how to know the total number of bars in the chart at the begining of the code (not via barstate.islast)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am wondering if there is a way to get the number of `bar` of the timeframe that my chart is in it from the beginning.

My goal is to use the final bar_index as a variable in my code, but the issue is that the bar index will increase by time. so I was wonderingwhat would be the solution here.

To explain more I am providing the example here.
Lets say I am in `2H` charts and there are in total 20K `bar_index` there, if I know the 20K for the beginning, I can then provide the condition that whatever total bars that my chart will have should be divided with `n` and then just apply my functions on a range of the results. but I dont know how I can know the total number of bars in the chart from the beginning...

I guess my question can also be ask as follow: can we somehow at the beginning of the code (not at the end via `barstate.islast`) know what is the total number of bars in the chart based on the timeframe we are in?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible to know. Your script will be executed on each bar starting from the first very bar. All the built-in variables such as `bar_index` will also be calculated on each bar. So, you cannot get that information until you wait till the last bar.

You have two options:

1. Use a for loop to do your calculations in a range (not recommended for performance reasons)
2. Enter the range yourself (bar index or some time) via the user settings

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is:
Assuming the data has no hole in them (that's why i use the>=15 min in my case since 1 min usually has little data in most of charts)

we can do this:

```
var timeframeinmin = 15
if barstate.isfirst
    maxBarIndex := int((timenow - time[0]) / (60000 * timeframeinmin))

plot(maxBarIndex, title="Max Bar Index Since Beginning", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: in your case timeframeinmin=120 should do it for 2H timeframe